# Ajax inside Ajax in jQuery : Not entering into second Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I went through all the related posts and nothing helped. Kindly help me here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_id").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http:********/"
        }).then(function(response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://**********/"
            }).then(function(response) {
                // Something
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: so is the first succeeding? Need to use browser dev tools to get more details

Comment: Yes first ajax call is success.What needs to be checked here ? am using chrome browser

Comment: Inspect actual requests in network tab. Also what is `$("#search_id")`? Is it form related?

Comment: In the `.then(function(response){` add `console.log(response)` to show the response in console

Comment: no errors in console and yes its form related.@charlietfl

Comment: which response you mean first @lhrec_106

Comment: well form might be submitting then .. what exactly is `$("#search_id")`? If it is a submit button need to prevent default form submit. As for inspecting requests...that is done in network tab. Also is page relaoding due to form?

Comment: its just a span id for drop down menu.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the second ajax call, see if you're getting there.

Comment: Why are you using the `.then()` method?  Why not execute the next ajax call within the parent success: function?

Comment: I tried the same ,its reading the second ajax line and getting out of the loop.. @Barmar

Comment: I had tried with success ,complete and call back .. No use.. something needs to be fixed here.. @David

Comment: Pretty sure those .then()'s are executed right after the request is sent, meaning they don't wait for the callback.

Comment: @Glubus That's the whole point of `.then`, it waits for the promise to be resolved.

Comment: Executing the next Ajax call within the success function should work. It might help if you include all of your code that you are using. I would guess there is a syntax error somewhere. Are you using `console.log(response)` to check for errors?